# How to get the installer path/name from the MAC UI installer(.pkg) start page

Tags: macos, installation, interface-builder, nib

We are trying to fetch installer *path/name* from the *MAC UI installer* before displaying the Custom *nib file*.
Below are the options tried:

- `hdiutil info -plist`
- Getting the environment variable `$PACKAGE_PATH`
- Scanning the current directory
- `ps -eaf` for listing the installer process name.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to perform the same task today and the best approach I've discovered is to `tail` or `cat` the `/var/log/install.log` file just after the pkg is launched & grep for `".pkg"`.

```
tail /var/log/install.log | grep ".pkg"
```

This prints the path & name of the most recently launched pkg file. From there, I can parse the line of the last occurrence to extract my own installer's path & name:

```
2022-04-21 12:50:01-04 mbp Installer[29570]: Opened from: /Users/[myuser]/Downloads/[myPkgFile].pkg
2022-04-21 12:50:01-04 mbp Installer[29570]: Product archive /Users/[myuser]/Downloads/[myPkgFile].pkg trustLevel=350
```

*Note*: So far, I've only tested this on Big Sur 11.6. The log syntax may differ on older or newer versions. I expect, though, that it hasn't changed much over the years.